# How to use a ks.cfg file to create a virtual machine.

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine

I'm studying for the RHCSA exam and both practice exams i'm using have asked me to do this.

The question is "Use the ks.cfg file provided to create a virtual machine with hostname blah blah and with an ipv4 address of blah blah"

I know first I have to modify that ks.cfg file with the appropriate host name and Static IP info. That I can do. I can also install the system-config-kickstart tool and set up the info using that. My question is where do I go from here to actually install the RHEL OS on the virtual machine. I already have KVM installed too.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow [this chapter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-putkickstarthere.html#s2-kickstart2-boot-media) of the official `RHEL Installation Guide` and prepare an ISO bootable image containing your `.ks` file, then boot off this image your `VM`